# Why is Maven including multiple versions of the same dependency?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a `Maven` java web app (.WAR) project that includes several libraries, including the `Wicket` libraries (but I don't think the problem is wicket itself, but rather with maven).

Here's the problem: even tho I only include `Wicket 6.20.0`, the resulting .WAR contains **two copies** of the Wicket libraries: `6.20.0` and `6.18.0`, as you can see in this screenshot:

[image]

Thinking of some conflicting imports I printed the dependency tree using the:

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

commnad... but **there is no mention of Wicket 6.18.0 in the dependency tree**! I also double-checked using Eclipse's "dependency hierarchy" view and I can confirm there's no trace of that import.

I even did a search for string "6.18.0" across the entire workspace with Eclipse, but it's nowhere to be found!

How can I find out what is causing the inclusion of that duplicate version of the library?

Comment: Can you please post your pom?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maven doesn't work in this way. 
The resolution of more than one dependency with the same artifactId and groupId but with a different version will result to a single dependency (the version used is no determinist).

The presence of two artifacts with the same artifactId and groupId but with two distinct versions in a same lib folder of the WAR is probably related to one of these :

- you don't execute `mvn clean package` but only `mvn package`.
- your use a bugged version of the Maven war plugin. Try to update it to check that.
- you have a Maven plugin that copies Wicket jars 6.18.0 in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder of the target folder during the build of the component.
- the maven WAR project you are building has as dependency an artifact of type WAR. In this case, the dependencies of the WAR dependency are so [overlaid](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html) in the  WAR project that you are building.

---

An interesting Maven issue about duplicated JAR because of WAR dependencies :

[JARs with different versions can be in WEB-INF/lib with war as dependencies](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MWAR-33)

---

[Your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44632079/270371) and your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44631683/why-is-maven-including-multiple-versions-of-the-same-dependency/44632079#comment76249628_44631926) indicate that actually you have a WAR dependency in your build.
Unfortunately, there is not really a good and long term effective solution to bypass this limitation.

As said in my comment, using the `packagingExcludes` property of the maven war plugin is a valid workaround for the actual issue :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <!-- ... -->
        <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/wicket-*-6.18.0.jar</packagingExcludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But beware, using that will do your build less robust through the time. 
The day where you update the version of the WAR dependency and that in its new version, it pulls again a different version of wicket, you have still a risk to have duplicate jars with two distinct versions in your built WAR.

Using [the overlay](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html) feature by specifying the `overlay` element of the `maven-war-plugin` is generally better as it focuses on the overlay applied for  the war dependency. It fixes the problem early.
As a result, you could define to exclude any wicket JARs from the WAR dependency :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>     
        <overlays>
            <overlay>
                <groupId>com.whatever.youlike</groupId> 
                <artifactId>myArtifact</artifactId>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>WEB-INF/lib/wicket-*.jar</exclude>                 
                </excludes>
            </overlay>
        </overlays>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This way is better but this is still a workaround.
The day where the dependency WAR is updated and that it pulls new dependencies (other than Wicket) that are declared in your actual build but with different versions, you may finish with the same kind of issue.

I think that declaring a dependency on a WAR artifact should be done only as we don't have choice.
As poms and projects refactoring are possible, introducing a common JAR dependency which the two WARs depend on and that contains only common sources and resources for the two WARs makes really things simpler.

Comment: +1, because your first bullet point pointed me in the right direction, see my answer below for details. Basically, it was a dependency, but a dependency of type "WAR" (I think they're called overlays?). These do not show up in the build tree / dep. hierarchy apparently.

Comment: Including a WAR type dependency in an artifact packaged as WAR is strongly discouraged for the reasons that you have noticed. It is not shown in `dependency:tree` as it is doesn't make part of the dependency resolution. It copies in a "raw" way jar contained in the lib/WAR dependency  in the lib/WAR built component. Sorry I don't know the exact name : the Monster Truck copy maybe ? ;)

Comment: I accepted your answer after the edit, since I dislike accepting my own answers :D Anyone interested in the specific details, see my own answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44632079/300741

Answer (score 2):

Well, I figured it out while poking around.

I had a dependency of type "war" in the project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.whatever.youlike</groupId>
    <artifactId>myArtifact</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.7-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <type>war</type>
</dependency>
```

Apparently (I wasn't aware of this, my fault here) these type of dependencies will include themselves in the classpath by copying all libs to the main WAR /libs folder, but these will NOT show app in the dependency tree / dependency hierarchy.

I solved by configuring an explicit exclusion in the WAR plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <!-- ... -->
        <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/wicket-*-6.18.0.jar</packagingExcludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Valid workaround.  +1 But it has some limitations. The day where the WAR dependency changes, you have still a risk to have duplicate jar with two distincts versions in your built WAR. I think that a pom refactoring would be a better solution at long term.

Comment: +1, you're right, it's not an elegant solution. We will align the two projects to use the same version for the next release. For now, this quick fix does the job.

Comment: A further clarification: I'm including it via WAR dependency because the included project is not present in our repositories in JAR form. I only need one single class from it, it would be excessive to refactor the entire project to extract a single class to a separate shared JAR.

Comment: You import a WAR only to use a class of it ? It is an important dependency with important side effect to address a very simple need. Personally, I would not refactor the whole project but I would extract this class and all classes making part of the same concern in its own artifact (JAR) and I would make depend the two WAR to this dependency. If you have already a artifact that is a good candidate to hold this or these classes, using it is still better as multiplicating the number of dependencies with not a lot of things inside is often a bad smell.

Comment: Yeah, I know, that's what I was implying... it will be done, but not in this release, as time is short, what I needed here was a quick fix ;)

Comment: If you only need a class from the WAR project you should change that project and let produce it a jar from the classes only (archiveClasses, archiveClasses) which produces a separate jar archive of the classes from within the WAR project. This can be used as a real dependency...

Answer (score 1):

Use `clean install` and the double dependency will probably be gone.

Comment: I always clean ;) The problem was a different one, see my own answer down below. Thanks anyway for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Because other libs can use same libs but different version or you tried different version and didn't make `mvn clean`

Comment: I was cleaning on each build. The problem was a different one, see my own answer for details. Thanks anyway for suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

The command `mvn dependency:tree` is telling you the correct information - what you are looking at here is an eclipse / build issue.

Clear out all the target and build areas in your project. If need be, check it out from source control to a new folder.

Alternatively you can build your project in IntelliJ IDEA, and see if you get the correct dependencies (most likely you will).